# Decryption not working in for modified files in s3bucket

Tags: java, encryption, amazon-s3

I have a java application which does a 256 bit encryption to files and uploads it to s3bucket. I had to move the content of the bucket from one location to another so I downloaded all the files from s3cmd and put it on another bucket assuming everything would work fine.

But now when I try to download the file I get following error and unreadable file, can I do something about it since most of the file in previous bucket was deleted.

```
WARNING: Unable to detect encryption information for object 'memberImage/87hdjkuhdklkj9889sdjljdfjldfj.jpg' in bucket 'onekong-bkt'. Returning object without decryption.
```

Comment: Related article: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2850096021478074. Perhaps the key material stored in metadata or instruction file was not moved along with the original S3 object?

Comment: @jarmod that sounds likely... *downloaded all the files from s3cmd and put it on another bucket*  would not preserve metadata if OP actually *downloaded* the files locally, and re-uploaded, and the metadata was stored as object metadata.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot so I do have the files downloaded from s3cmd with me can I somehow reupload it to the bucket preserving the metadata? If so that would be a great help

Comment: Unfortunately, my working assumption would be that you lost the metadata when you *downloaded* the files.

Answer (score 1):

The best method for moving data between Amazon S3 buckets is by using the CopyObject command. This directly copies the data between buckets without having to download the content -- and it even works between regions.

Simpler yet is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It has a `sync` command that can replicate directories between buckets. This would also copy the metadata.

See: [AWS CLI sync command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)